# Deploying to OC4j: Unable to find/read file META-INF/application.xml

Tags: java, deployment, oc4j, continuum

Continuum build server deploys to my oc4j instance I get the following error it seems every other build.

09/03/10 13:47:49 Notification ==>Operation failed with error:
Unable to find/read file META-INF/application.xml in C:\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\rrs (META-INF/application.xml)

Continuum is running in a windows environment

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Continuum, but I face this OC4J message during some app deployments.

The error message shows that the application.xml file is missing inside the EAR you are deploying. You are deploying an application called rss in the home instance. Inside the rss.ear file must be present a META-INF/application.xml with a content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
    <display-name>rss</display-name>
    <module>
           <ejb>rss.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

In some step of your building process you must define and include the application.xml file. Perhaps the tool you are using could do this, but need some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard this is a windows issue sometimes. I have also noticed that in eclipse using the oc4j server adapter I see this behavior when my publish command fails to deploy my war due to any error at all. Then the next time I try to publish/deploy The error for "Unable to find/read file META-INF/application.xml" is displayed and the deploy fails and must be repeated once. It is as if the failed deploy left some remnants in the wrong place. not a solution just some observations...